# Is there a better way to distinguish between string id parameters and action names in my routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

**Problem**

I have a `TagsController`, with the standard CRUD Actions.  But for the `Details` result I would rather not include the action name in the url. I want URLs like this:

- tags
- tags/my-tag-url     //no action name specified
- tags/create
- tags/edit/123
- ... and as normal ...

But obviously, there is no way for the routing to distinguish between an action name and the `my-tag-url` parameter.

---

**Possible Solution 1**

Create 2 routes. One for the `tags/{my-tag-url}` route, and another for the `tags/{action}/{id}` routes.

**Downside:**  The requirement to adorn one of the routes with a constraint - either checking for the existince of `my-tag-url` in the DB, or checking against a list of the action names on the controller.
(BTW - is either of these prefereable over the other?)

---

**Possible Solution 2**

Change `tags/my-tag-url` to `tag/my-tag-url` (notice singular) and map this to a different controller.

**Downside:** The urls are no longer 'hackable'.  I can't just remove the `my-tag-url` to get to the index page listing all tags.

Answer (score 0):

> But obviously, there is no way for the routing to distinguish between
>   an action name and the my-tag-url parameter.

Constraints are the means to achieve this.

> The requirement to adorn one of the routes with a constraint - either
>   checking for the existince of my-tag-url in the DB, or checking
>   against a list of the action names on the controller.

You've given yourself an `either-or` situation but you can also (preferably) use the regex option so no lookup is required:

```
routes.MapRoute("blog", "{year}/{month}/{day}"
, new {controller="blog", action="index"}
, new {year=@"\d{4}", month=@"\d{2}", day=@"\d{2}"});
```

In your case:

```
routes.MapRoute("tagurl", "{tagurl}"
    , new {controller="tags", action="TagRedirector"}
    , new {tagurl=@"@"^htt\w*"});


public ActionResult TagRedirector(string tagurl)
{
..
}
```

This will likely run into the dangerous request territory however, so if your tags have no pattern (`www.`)? that you can filter for then you could just as easily use `!` operator in your regex pattern to knockout the names of action methods on your controller that should be filtered out i.e. only use this route if `{tagsurl}` is not "index,other, whatever"

Comment: Thank you.  This is the approach I took in the end. I have a constraint which checks against a (cached) list of actions on the TagsController.